# Mistake in calculating Green's function

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, boundary-value-problem, greens-function

> Solve the BVP
>
> $$y'' = f(x) = x, \qquad y(0) = 0, \qquad y'(1) = 0$$
>
> with the usage of Green's function.

First of all, the solution should be

$$y = \frac{x^3}{6} - \frac{x}{2}.$$

According to [this](http://www.macs.hw.ac.uk/~bernd/F13YB1/odenotes5.pdf) explanation, for calculating $G$, we first need a fundamental system of the associated homogenous equation $y'' = 0$. We take $u_1 = x$ and $u_2 = 1$. According to the boundary values, we now choose $y_1 = x$ and $y_2 = 1$, then we have $y_1(0) = 0$ and $y_2'(1) = 0$. Furthermore, $W(y_1, y_2) = -1$, so it follows

$$G(x,s) = \begin{cases} -s \qquad &0 \leq s \leq x \\
-x \qquad &x \leq s \leq 1.
\end{cases}$$

Then I obtain for the solution

$$y = \int_0^1 G(x,s) f(s) \ \mathrm{d}s = -\frac{1}{3},$$

which is obviously not the correct answer. Where is my mistake?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

\begin{align}
y &= \int_0^1 G(x,s) f(s) \ \mathrm{d}s \\
 &= \int_0^x (-s) s \ \mathrm{d}s + \int_x^1 (-x) s \ \mathrm{d}s \\
 &= -\frac{x^3}3-\frac{x}2(1-x^2)=\frac{x^3}6-\frac{x}2
\end{align}
which seems to be correct. What were the steps that led you to the wrong solution?